# Is it time that we allow [game-identification] tagged questions without a audiovisual artifact?

Tags: discussion, game-identification

Feels weird to see game-identification questions pop up on the real-time feed, not through Gaming.SE, but through SciFi.SE.  Perhaps it's time we revisit the rules and guidelines established for those kinds of questions?

If SciFi.SE can handle identification questions, whether or not they contain audiovisual artifacts, and science fiction works have encompassed a far greater scope than just video games, surely Arqade.SE can do the same?

Comment: I believe SciFi has always accepted identification questions, I don't think that's a recent development.

Comment: I strongly feel that it is not worth re-litigating this issue. The [game-identification tag wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-identification/info) contains an extensive explanation of the reasons for our policy, which was hashed out in many meta post over a long period of time. If you would like to propose that something specific in there no longer applies, or that something major was overlooked, it would be worth considering, but otherwise, the decision has been made.

Comment: You're not really providing an argument for why these questions should be allowed in this post, or ideas for what to do about the issues that were brought up time and time again over the years.

Comment: It's especially absurd when game identification questions end up on sci-fi and fantasy and answered.

Comment: As they currently stand, game identification questions on Arqade are basically "does anyone know how to use Google's reverse image search?" questions. I personally would like to see game identification questions. I think they're a lot more interesting than the "How do I do X in Minecraft?" questions which make up the bulk of the site.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that what you're asking is "should we allow ITG questions based on artifacts other than game assets or screenshots?". If you actually mean something else, please clarify your question.

The main issue is that a lot of games are quite hard to conclusively identify from a description. For example, would you be able to tell FIFA 2020 from FIFA 2019 just from someone describing it? Would you be able to tell apart Call of Duty Modern Warfare from Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2019 from a campaign description? If I said "strategy game in which you control historical armies", would you be able to say conclusively whether it's Age of Empires, Empire Earth, Rise of Nations, Stronghold or maybe even something else?

We ask for a tangible piece from the game because we're feasibly able to do that, and our ITG questions are intended for people to be able to know what the game is they saw displayed somewhere. The story Identification questions on SFF are intended to help people remember the movie they saw, book they read or game they played, set in an SFF world.

Comment: Scifi has already so many tropes that overlap with one another and are present in thousands upon thousands of works across the last century.   If they can differentiate a work based on those small minute details, the same can be said for video games, even those with seemingly no difference.  The differences in Call of Duty games can come down to details like perks, weaponry, and gameplay modes, and those can be distinguished from one another.

Comment: > "strategy game in which you control historical armies", would you be able to say conclusively whether it's Age of Empires, Empire Earth, Rise of Nations, Stronghold

These also have very big details that separate them from one another.  We can always ask the OP for more clarification, but just because someone says "harvest sim" doesn't mean we can't differentiate between Stardew Valley, Harvest Moon, Minecraft, or Farming Simulator, they all have differences amongst one another that can narrow down a search.

Comment: I don't like the examples or the way you've framed your examples because they insinuate that people have no way to differentiate between games of a similar genre. It's insulting, really, to assume so.   Even Call of Duty games have vast differences, such as the developer, the availability of platforms, the era those games are situated in, etc.

Comment: @childe observe the r/tipofmyjoystick subreddit, which is exactly what you're describing: they have a pronounced format with active moderation to clear out bad questions. we can't dedicate moderation time to one tag.